# iOS Crash : Can't access memory location

Tags: iphone, crash, uikit

I'm seeing a lot of these crashes in my crash reporter, but I have NO idea what could be causing it.

I can't get it to reproduce locally.

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x70000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3ba9f5b0 _objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                               0x35a73313 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1311
2   UIKit                               0x35a8a7cf -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 207
3   UIKit                               0x35a46803 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 259
4   QuartzCore                          0x357f0d8b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 215
5   QuartzCore                          0x357f0929 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 461
6   QuartzCore                          0x357f185d CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 17
7   QuartzCore                          0x357f1243 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 239
8   QuartzCore                          0x357f1051 CA::Transaction::commit() + 317
9   QuartzCore                          0x357f0eb1 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 61
10  CoreFoundation                      0x33c106cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 21
11  CoreFoundation                      0x33c0e9c1 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 277
12  CoreFoundation                      0x33c0ed17 __CFRunLoopRun + 743
13  CoreFoundation                      0x33b81ebd _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
14  CoreFoundation                      0x33b81d49 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
15  GraphicsServices                    0x377362eb _GSEventRunModal + 75
16  UIKit                               0x35a97301 _UIApplicationMain + 1121
17  Our App Name                        0x00011d83 main (main.m:21)
```

- The crash report has been symbolicated
- I know it's the UITableView trying to update.
- I know it's the table view trying to access memory it's not allowed to access.
- I don't know what table view it is.  It could be any of them in the app.

If you have ideas about more debugging info that would be great.

---

Edit:

This is happening in the production app.  I **CAN'T** get this to reproduce locally in debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a bug in an animation that repeated wasn't getting properly canceled when the containing table view scrolled.  Haven't see this in the crash reports since that fix went out.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Edit Scheme > Run > Diagnostics > Enable Guard Malloc & Enable Zombie Objects

[image]

This should give you more information on the next crash!  I had a similar experience where a library I was using edited a bit outside of the buffer it was using.  It rarely ever crashed but Guard Malloc spotted it right away. Even though the crash was only happening in an AD Hoc distribution and never with the debugger. NSZombies will help if the memory is getting dealloced before the message is sent. However, the NSZombies will only be helpful at the time it crashes.

Comment: That would be great, but I can't reproduce it locally.  It's only happening on the app store, when I can't turn on Guard or Zombies.

Comment: In my situation it was always a co-workers device that crashed.  I also could not produce it locally. If a memory address is being corrupted but your device never tries to use it then you may never (or once in a blue moon) be able to reproduce.  Guard Malloc was still able to spot the error for me even though I didn't crash.  Give it a try with your source :)